# How can I make the MEAN.js default Article User save into Array of Users instead?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meanjs

I'm trying to make the default Article create page add a User to an Array of Users in MongoDB.

I do not know how the

```
ref: 'User'
```

is working here. Can anyone explain why this isn't working or just point me to a specific location to read about this in the docs?

```
MEAN.js default template properly assigns the current window's user:

    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
```

```
My attempt which isn't saving the User but instead creates an empty Array:

    users: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the valid syntax to save array in mongodb by using mongoose schema is:

```
users: [{        
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.